# Root Context path in spring application

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I am running application using tomcat server, when server start i will get url

http://localhost:8080/TestApp/

and displaying index.jsp file but when i click link in index file it is displaying url like

http://localhost:8080/testsuccess

but it should display like

http://localhost:8080/TestApp/testsuccess

can any please help me to solve this.

SpringConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.testapp")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SpringConfiguration {
   @Bean
   public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}
}
```

SpringWebAppInitializer.java

public class SpringWebAppInitializer                                        implements                            WebApplicationInitializer   {

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    appContext.register(SpringConfiguration.class);
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet(
            "SpringDispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");
}

}
```

MyController.java

```
@Controller
public class MyFirstController 
 {

@RequestMapping(value = "/" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String testApp() throws Exception{
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/testsuccess", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String testAppSuccess() {
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    return "success";
}

}
```

Comment: Paste your spring Controller class...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

got it i should use

```
 <a href="<c:url value='/testsuccess'/>">Next</a>
```

it will give the context path.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem comes from the link inside your index.jsp. They might look like `<a href="/testsuccess">...</a>` You should use either jstl or spring tag lib to handle links / urls in your pages. They both have the ability to prepend the deployment / context path of your application.

jstl example:
with taglib `xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"` included you can create an anchor like `<a href="<c:url value='/testsuccess'/>">..</a>`

spring example:
with taglib `xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags"` your link will be created in two steps:

```
<spring:url value="/testsuccess" var="myurl" htmlEscape="true"/>
<a href="${myurl}">...</a>
```

*Update:* Wrong function name in  jstl taglib version.

Comment: Hi,thank for your suggestion i used as you suggested jsp taglib but its same thing happening.my code is ..                                                        <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%><title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 
 <a href="<c:out value='/testsuccess'/>">Get Next Page</a>
</body>

Comment: got it instead of <c:out> i should use <c:url>

Comment: sorry, my typo. Some lag between brain and keyboard ;)

Comment: can you suggest me how to get root context path in html.

Comment: You cannot get this in pure html because the tags mentioned above used in jsp getting compiled and not interpreted on runtime. Of course you might also process html files with the view resolver.

Comment: i removed index.jsp and i used index.html but when i click on link <td><a href="/testsuccess">Next</a></td> it is giving url like   http://localhost:8080/testsuccess insted of this             http://localhost:8080/TestApp/testsuccess

Comment: because it is a simple anchor prefixed with / (root). You may remove it and get the desired behavior. But keep in mind that it is only a relative link without any knowledge about your application.

Comment: then what should i do to get root path here

Comment: Just remove the '/'. You don't need the root path (do you mean context path?) if this link is only in the index.html file. You don't have any possibility to get the application path in there unless the html file gets processed by a viewresolver e.g. has jsp content and gets processed by the internalviewresolver (or you use other view frameworks like thymeleaf).